# ListView position doesn't save after close

Tags: android, arrays, listview, arraylist, save

I managed to change my `ListView`'s item position but after I close my app, the position goes back to before I made any changes.

What and how do I save the item's arranged position?

Populating `ListView`

```
String[] SavedFiles;
String dataDr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_address);

    dataDr = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
    showDirFile(dataDr);
}

void showDirFile(String dirpth)
{
    String path = dirpth+"/files";
    Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
    File f = new File(path);
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);

    SavedFiles = new String[file.length];
    for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
    {
        Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());

        SavedFiles[i] = file[i].getName();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            SavedFiles);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

to change item position and save them to an `Array`

```
Collections collections;

void positionChange(){

    //to store arrays into ArrayList
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myDataFiles));

    //to get the item's position @ get the first item in array if multiple arrays exist
    String currentPos = String.valueOf(intArrayList.get(0));
    int oldPos = Integer.valueOf(currentPos);
    int newPos = oldPos-1;

    //Swap position @ move up list
    collections.swap(newList, oldPos, newPos);

    //store ArrayList data into arrays
    myDataFiles = newList.toArray(myDataFiles);

    intArrayList.clear();

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Edit**

Do note that the items in the `Array` was filled from `dataDr = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;`

Perhaps I need to find a way to save the arrangement position in my directory?

Comment: When your items changes their position again? When you minimize the app and resume again or when you completely shutdown the app?

Comment: @AwaisAhmad when I completely shutdown my app. Now I noticed that it also reverts back to original when I open a new activity or press my device's back button

Comment: just keep the position in a sharedpreference and set it on starting up the app

Comment: @Rithe alright, I've studied a bit about sharedpreference and it seems to do the job. But before I implement this, how will this retrieve my item's position since I fill my `Array` using `dataDr = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;`. Please post as answer because I'm not sure how to implement this

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned in the comments, [`SharedPreferences`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) will do the trick. Initialize it in your `onCreate` method.

```
// use member variable for this (private SharedPreferences prefs)
prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Since the position of your item may change, it would be wise to store the file name instead of the postion. Good place for this could be the `onItemSelected` (therefor you have to add a listener to your listview).

```
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    prefs.edit().putString("yourKey", listView.getItemAtPosition(position)).apply();
  }
});
```

To set the correct position after starting up your app you have to get the position of the file in your `SavedFile` object.

Loading string from `SharedPreferences`:

```
String fileName = prefs.getString("yourKey", "");
```

After initialization of your listview and adapter just iterate through the list and compare strings. If the string matches, take the position and set it to your listview object.

```
for(int i = 0; i < SavedFiles.length; i++){
  if(fileName.equals(SavedFiles[i])){
    listview.setSelection(i);
    break;
  }
}
```